# Firebase Storage Loading Images Speed

Tags: firebase, performance

(I am using Ionic Angular & storing images in firebase storage)

I have a set of functions that load my user's friends, friend requests, and other data. This includes getting the profile images of all the friends and friend requests. Here is the code I use to get profile images:

```
 // ? gets images for Users
  async getImage(link: string): Promise<string>
  {
    let url = '';
    if(!link.includes('https://')){ // if has already been converted
    if (link == '' || link == undefined) { 
      return 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pmpkin-e52d5.appspot.com/o/Users%2Fblank-profile-picture-973460_640.png?alt=media&token=*******'
     }
      let storageRef = this.storage.ref('Users');
      await storageRef.child(link).getDownloadURL()
        .then( (val) => { url = val; } )
        .catch( (error) => { console.log(error); } );
    }else{
     url = link;
  }
    return URL;
  }
```

When I remove this from my code, the time it takes to load the other data is just 350 milliseconds, as shown in the last `console.log`:

[image: init img]

But, when I add the getImages() function in, it takes much longer (almost 10X):

[image: next img]

Does anyone know how to make this function slower or get the images differently from firebase storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution to my problem. Here is the new code for the image stuff:

```js
  // ? gets images for Users
  async getImage(link: string): Promise<string>
  {
    let url = '';
    let token = '******';
    if(!link.includes('https://')){ // if has already been converted
      if (link == '' || link == undefined) { 
        return 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pmpkin-e52d5.appspot.com/o/Users%2Fblank-profile-picture-973460_640.png?alt=media&token=*******'
      }
      let fullLink = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pmpkin-e52d5.appspot.com/o/Users%2F${link}?alt=media&token=${token}`;
      console.log(fullLink)
      return fullLink;
    }else{
      url = link;
    }
    return url;
  }
```